# laravel delete form is not working

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div style="float:left;" class="col-md-8">
            <h3>Currency</h3>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;" class="col-md-4">        
        <a href="/currency/create" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm ml-3" style="float: right"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color:white;"></i>Add New</a>
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search" class="form-control-sm col-md-8 ml-1" style="float:right;"><br><br>
    </div>   
</div>

    @if(count($currencies) > 0 )
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" >
            <thead>
            <tr><th scope="col">ID</th><th scope="col">Currency</th><th scope="col">Country</th><th scope="col" colspan="2" style="text-align:right">Actions</th></tr>
            </thead>
        @foreach($currencies as $currency)        
            <tr><td scope="row">{{$currency->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$currency->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$currency->country}}</td>
                {!!Form::open(['action'=>['CurrencyController@destroy', $currency->id], 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
                {{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
                 @csrf
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:white;"></i>Delete</button>   
                    <a href="/currency/{{$currency->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right" ><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color:white;"></i>Edit</a></td></tr>       
                {!!Form::close() !!}               
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{$currencies->links()}}
    @else
        <p> No Data Available </p>    
    @endif

@endsection
```

Hi all, The delete form is not submitting in this code and I tried so many thing but I could not figure out the issue. Please help me with this.

Comment: adding `csrf` field might fix the issue.

Comment: Please also provide your relevant routes

Comment: sorry I tried it already. It was not working.. Now I updated above code also.

Comment: @ab_ab csrf is included if it's LaravelCollective in the Form::open method

Comment: Do you see any errors? Or whats not working?

Comment: form::hidden should be {!! Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE") !!}

Comment: Form itself not submitting.. And I am using Laravel Collective

Comment: @SimonR I have tried it.. no luck

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov Form is not submitting..

Comment: Try to move your form inside `<td>`

Comment: @SevaKalashnikov Great.. Now It works.. But I could not understand the issue.. The same code worked fine on another application.

Comment: OK I posted it as an answer since it worked for your case. Your html code is getting messed up and submit button does not active the right form since you printing multiple ones in your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your html is wrong, you open, close your form and place `@csrf` outside your `td` tag while submit button is inside it

Try to move your form definition inside `td` tag like:

```
<td>
    {!!Form::open(['action'=>['CurrencyController@destroy', $currency->id], 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
{{Form::hidden('_method','DELETE')}}
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="color:white;"></i>Delete</button>   
        <a href="/currency/{{$currency->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:right" ><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color:white;"></i>Edit</a>
    {!!Form::close() !!}    
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method in the actual `form` tag to DELETE? By default if you are using something like `route::resource` in your routes, it will automatically assign the DELETE method to the route, not the POST.

I can see you're specifying the delete method in a hidden element anyway, but its worth a try.

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['CurrencyController@destroy', $currency->id], 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
```

If you're never quite sure, run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal inside your project root directory, and it will give you a full list of the routes and methods for your application.